# get next 10 results (Map Locations nearby) by clicking on list view android

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, kml

I have found the method to draw placemarks of nearby places(Restaurants,Theaters,etc.) but it works only for 10 places and I generate the list of that places...

Problem is>>
I want to add last list-item to show option for next("in future previous") 10 results...
Is there any to generate "kml" for that....or any other way???

Thanks In Advance.
Please Help Me as this includes in my project work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not make sense

But anyway here is how to generate a kml .

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&output=kml

Where lat, lon is your location.

Parse the kml that you get using a SAX parser the you get a list of places to eat.

Edit :

To get restaurants from 10 to 20

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&start=10&output=kml

Comment: I am already using this link but it gives the kml having **restaurant (1 - 10)**  I want next 10 result i.e.11-20 and so on for better and more options to user.  Thanks for Reply.